# Professional Rider Database

Tags: racing

I'm looking for a downloadable database of professional (road) riders, containing age, height, weight, etc. The only thing I've found so far is http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/sports/CYC/mens-road-race-individual.html which seems to have a good amount of information, but is not easily downloadable, as I would have to go to each rider page individually go obtain the data. Any other sources out there?

Comment: Also [Pro Cycling Stats](http://www.procyclingstats.com), but the data is equally spread out. After you've compiled it, you could add a page to Wikipedia :-)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could simply write an email to the sports-reference.com people and ask nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that anyone who has compiled that data would allow you download it.

Cycling News has a really good database at http://www.cyclingnews.com/teams

You can download rankings that include all the riders with name, country and age at http://www.cqranking.com/men/asp/gen/downloads.asp

Other than that I would try the UCI or each country's governing body, but it's unlikely they would have height and weight stats.